# Unexpected end of JSON input at parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I'm tring to write to an exist JSON and i've noticed that I should read the file insert the new item and then writing again , its working on most times but sometimes I recieve this error " Unexpected end of JSON input at parse ()" , and hole data in json are deleted .

```
app.post(APIClonePath,(req,res)=>{
  const body = req.body
  let cloneTicket:Ticket = body.ticket
  let ticketID = body.id
  let fs = require('fs')
  // @ts-ignore
  fs.readFile('./data.json',(err,data) =>{
    if(err){
      throw new Error('ERROR in reading JSON')
      // res.send(false)
    }
    let ticketsInJSON = JSON.parse(data)
    let indexOfOriginTicket
    for(let index = 0; index < ticketsInJSON.length ; index++){
      if(ticketsInJSON[index].id.valueOf() === ticketID){
        indexOfOriginTicket = index
        break
      }
    }
    // @ts-ignore
    ticketsInJSON.splice(indexOfOriginTicket,0,cloneTicket)
    let writingArray = JSON.stringify(ticketsInJSON)
    writeFile('./data.json',writingArray,function (){})
  })


  res.send(true)


})
```

Comment: May be data is null, check the null data if null don't apply parse.

To check the data add the console log after receive the data.

Answer (score 0):

1st. mode fs declaration to the file header with all other requires.
2nd. you use // @ts-ignore as this would be TS file, and you are using require instead of import.

3rd. you answer user TRUE before you even read the file, you also dont have any precaution against many file access in this code. Imagine more than one ppl are executing your code, one read the file, the the same guy starts writing to the file, while other guy just started reading the not saved file - you never know what can happen.

4th. you ignore anything from writeFile function which can tell you information about errors while writing file.

5th. if you do not find index, you try to splice with undefined instead of index - that also can make problems